# AngularJS : Two-way binding between a textarea and ng-repeat-ed inputs

Tags: angularjs

I was going to ask this as a question, but I figured out a solution. So at this point, I'm looking for a critique of my solution.

1. I've got a static `textarea`, and an `input` with an `ng-repeat` directive.
2. As the user types a sentence into the `textarea`, a `input` is rendered for each word in the sentence.
3. Then if the user updates the text in any `input`, the corresponding word in the `textarea` sentence is updated (really the whole sentence is recreated).

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/bSjtOK?p=preview

### Questions

Keeping in mind that I'm only 2 weeks into my AngularJS learning:

- Did I write this in the "angular" way?
- Is there something I could have done better?
- Am I violating any no-nos?

### Abbreviated Code

#### HTML

```html
<textarea ng-model="sentence" ng-change="parseSentence()" style="width: 100%; height: 15em;"></textarea>

<input type="text" ng-repeat="w in words" ng-model="w.word" ng-change="buildSentance(w)" />
```

#### JavaScript

```js
function WordCtrl($scope, debounce) {

    $scope.words = [];
    $scope.sentence = 'Hello there how are you today?';

    // this is called when the textarea is changed
    // it splits up the textarea's text and updates $scope.words 
    $scope.parseSentence = function() {

        var words = $scope.sentence.split(/\s+/g);
        var wordObjects = [];

        for (var i=0;i<words.length;i++) {          
          wordObjects.push({word: words[i]});
        }

        if ((words.length == 1) && (words[0] === '')) {
          $scope.words = [];
        } else {
          $scope.words = wordObjects;
        }

    };

    $scope.parseSentenceDebounced = debounce($scope.parseSentence, 1000, false);

    $scope.buildSentance = function(w) {

        var words = [];

        for (var i=0;i<$scope.words.length;i++) {
          var word = $scope.words[i].word;
          if (word.replace(/\s+/g,'') !== '') {
            words.push(word);
          }
        }

        $scope.sentence = words.join(' ');

        // if the user puts a space in the input
        // call parseSentence() to update $scope.words
        if (w.word.indexOf(' ') > -1) {
          $scope.parseSentenceDebounced();
        }

    }

    $scope.parseSentence();

}
```

Comment: Looks good, though it would be better to use $watch instead of ` ngChange` because of how `ngModel` directive works (_there is a difference between the view value and the actual value, you might get into a race condition while the value is being converted_). Just one question: why do you debounce exactly?

Comment: I add the debounce because if `parseSentence()` is called immediately (ng-change fires on keypress), the view is rerendered and focus on the `input` is lost.

Comment: @fastreload +1 for suggesting $watch ... should negate the need to debounce, no?

Comment: @jlmcdonald Indeed yes

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I got $watch working for `$scope.sentence`, but I can't get it for `$scope.words`. Suggestions? http://plnkr.co/edit/hsLtBI?p=preview

Comment: In response to your last comment - a basic $watch on an array will only fire if the whole array is reassigned. it won't watch for changes to items in the array. Passing true as a third parameter (i.e. `$scope.$watch('words', onWordsChanged, true)`) will tell angular to do a 'deep-watch' or look at `$scope.$watchCollection` instead.

Comment: One more thing to look out for is your use of auto-generated objects. You generally want to avoid generating objects from the same data in angular as it considers 2 different objects as different even if they have identical keys and values. This will bite you with `$digest` iteration errors if you try to use any complicated filters. It will however consider 2 different arrays equal if they have the same sets of objects in them. For this reason I would just save an array of simple strings (`['hello', 'world']`) rather than an array of objects (`[{word: 'hello'}, {word: 'world'}]`)

Answer (score 1):

Interesting issue you are having.  I put your code on my page and the first thing I noticed is that you cannot pass debounce in the controller method.

Next Problem I noticed is that you have an ng-change that changes the values on another box with ng-change.  I changed the event to Keypress to stop the digest in a digest.

Here it is working in JSFiddle [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/jfallin/c2pxx9wc/)

The code:

**HTML**

```
    <body ng-app="portal">
    <div ng-controller="WordCtrl">
    <textarea ng-model="sentence" ng-keypress="parseSentence()" style="width: 100%; height: 15em;"></textarea>
    <input type="text" ng-repeat="w in words" ng-model="w.word" ng-keypress="buildSentance(w)" />
    </div>
    </body>
```

**Javascript**

```
angular.module("portal",[]).controller("WordCtrl",function($scope) { 
    $scope.words = [];
    $scope.sentence = 'Hello there how are you today?';
    $scope.parseSentence = function () {
        var words = $scope.sentence.split(/\s+/g);
        var wordObjects = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            wordObjects.push({ word: words[i] });
        }
        if ((words.length == 1) && (words[0] === ''))
        {
            $scope.words = [];
        }
        else
        {
            $scope.words = angular.copy(wordObjects);
        }
    }

    $scope.buildSentance = function (w) {

        var words = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.words.length; i++) {
            var word = $scope.words[i].word;
            if (word.replace(/\s+/g, '') !== '') {
                words.push(word);
            }
        }

        $scope.sentence = words.join(' ');

        // if the user puts a space in the input
        // call parseSentence() to update $scope.words
        if (w.word.indexOf(' ') > -1) {
            $scope.parseSentenceDebounced();
        }
    }
    $scope.parseSentence();

    });
```

Hope this solves your issue.